# Tag request [visual-foxpro]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

Just edited a [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/220565/146810) mistagged as VBA to instead use a new [visual-foxpro](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual-foxpro) tag.

After looking at tag synonyms for VBA, I see there is no [visual-basic-applications](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual-basic-applications) tag, so perhaps the new tag I created should instead be [vfp](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vfp) if abbreviations are preferred?

NB: Stack Overflow has [both tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/visual-foxpro/synonyms) with [vfp](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vfp) mapped onto [visual-foxpro](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual-foxpro), unlike [visual-basic-applications](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual-basic-applications) which maps to [vba](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vba).

Comment: [tag:vfp] is hard to read with the default fonts used by SE, so I'm not a fan of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've forced the edit, (the queues aren't well attended during these hours) so [visual-foxpro](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual-foxpro) is now officially in use.

Although [vfp](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vfp) is somewhat hard to read, we may want to create it anyway to make sure people can find it.

Thank you for bringing it to our attention. Every programming language should have it's own tag, so you did exactly what had to be done.

Comment: Do you creating a synonym vfp -> visual-foxpro would be a good idea?

Comment: @Peilonrayz Probably, although I don't expect the volume of questions to be so high it's going to be a problem. Since there are reasons to do it and no reasons not to do it, go for it.